# 'uncallable object' error while Filtering DataFrame based on time range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I wanted to filter data from a DataFrame but I got an error I did not expect.

this is a portion of the file:

```
0   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2021-04-02 06:25:52+00:00   4.0     NaN
1   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2021-04-02 05:12:34+00:00   4.0     NaN
2   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2021-04-02 05:11:03+00:00   4.0     NaN
3   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2021-04-02 03:33:24+00:00   5.0     NaN
4   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2021-04-02 03:31:49+00:00   4.5     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
44992   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2018-01-01 01:27:26+00:00   5.0     NaN
44994   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2018-01-01 01:19:24+00:00   5.0     NaN
44996   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2018-01-01 01:09:56+00:00   5.0     NaN
44997   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2018-01-01 01:08:11+00:00   5.0     NaN
44999   The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Ap...   2018-01-01 01:01:16+00:00   
5.0     NaN
```

The following was my code:

```
from pytz import utc
import datetime
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("reviews.csv",parse_dates  =['Timestamp'])

data[(data['Timestamp'] >= datetime( 2020 , 1, 5,tzinfo = utc)) & (data["Timestamp"]<= datetime(2020 ,5 ,4,tzinfo = utc))]
```

This was the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-049df4c17b8a> in <module>
----> 1 data[(data['Timestamp'] >= datetime( 2020 , 1, 5,tzinfo = utc)) & (data["Timestamp"]<= datetime(2020 ,5 ,4,tzinfo = utc))]

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

All these were being executed in the jupyter notebook

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `datetime(...)` should be `datetime.datetime(...)`

Comment: Its pretty common to `import datetime as dt` and then do `dt.datetime`. Some will do `from datetime import datetime` but that can cause problems if you want other objects in the `datetime` module later.